# How to run git clone and run in the repo in DockerOperator at the same time?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I set up base images and project images in docker hub and then I run the docker operator to run task in airflow. But, I frequently change my source code so that I need to build and upload my image everytime. It is really time consuming.

My idea is not to use project image. If I run git clone and run in the repo at the same time, I could get rid of necessity of the project iamge that causes time consuming and routine tasks.